# Confused on notation for probability

Tags: probability, notation

Does P(x, y | z) mean the joint distribution of (x and y), given z, or does it mean the joint distribution of x and (y given z)?

Comment: It's the first one.

Comment: "(y given z)" does not exist as a random variable anyway, so, by elimination...